# How to inject java.nio.file.Path dependency using @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties-file, java.nio.file

I'm using Spring Boot and have the following Component class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="file")
public class FileManager {

    private Path localDirectory;

    public void setLocalDirectory(File localDirectory) {
        this.localDirectory = localDirectory.toPath();
    }

...

}
```

And the following yaml properties file:

```
file:
     localDirectory: /var/data/test
```

I would like to remove the reference of java.io.File (of setLocalDirectory) by replacing with java.nio.file.Path. However, I receive a binding error when I do this. Is there way to bind the property to a Path (e.g. by using annotations)?

Answer (score 8):

To add to jst's answer, the Spring Boot annotation **@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding** can be used for Spring Boot to recognize the converter for property binding, as mentioned in the documentation under [Properties Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-conversion):

```
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class StringToPathConverter implements Converter<String, Path> {

  @Override
  public Path convert(String pathAsString) {
    return Paths.get(pathAsString);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if there is a way with annotations, but you could add a Converter to your app. Marking it as a @Component with @ComponentScan enabled works, but you may have to play around with getting it properly registered with the ConversionService otherwise.

```
@Component
public class PathConverter implements Converter<String,Path>{

 @Override
 public Path convert(String path) {
     return Paths.get(path);
 }
```

When Spring sees you want a Path but it has a String (from your application.properties), it will lookup in its registry and find it knows how to do it.

Comment: I put this into a @Configuration class and made the Converter<String, Path> a bean (@Bean). That took care of registration using [Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration)

Answer (score 2):

I took up james idea and defined the converter within the spring boot configuration:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class Configuration {
    public class PathConverter implements Converter<String, Path> {

        @Override
        public Path convert(String path) {
            return Paths.get(path);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
    public PathConverter getStringToPathConverter() {
        return new PathConverter();
    }
}
```